# vuejs not rendering components

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vue, and I can not seem to figure out why is the new Vue ()" function does not work properly. This is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>First App</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
     <greeting></greeting>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Need to see the javascript code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `main.js` file in your `<body>` tag. This happens because the javascript is executed before the dom was loaded. If you have any question after let me know.